# 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in RdKafka.dll

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

when i try to implement a consumer like the example mentionened in readme section the following 
line

```
var config = new Config() { GroupId = "example-csharp-consumer" };
```

causes this exception

```
    System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=Der Typeninitialisierer für "RdKafka.Internal.LibRdKafka" hat eine Ausnahme verursacht.
  Source=RdKafka
  TypeName=RdKafka.Internal.LibRdKafka
  StackTrace:
       bei RdKafka.Internal.LibRdKafka.conf_new()
       bei RdKafka.Internal.SafeConfigHandle.Create()
       bei RdKafka.Config..ctor()
       bei kafka_consumer_example.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\stc\Development\git\kafka-consumer-example\Program.cs:Zeile 18.
       bei System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       bei System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233052
       Message=Die DLL "librdkafka": Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E) kann nicht geladen werden.
       Source=RdKafka
       TypeName=""
       StackTrace:
            bei RdKafka.Internal.LibRdKafka.NativeMethods.rd_kafka_version()
            bei RdKafka.Internal.LibRdKafka.version()
            bei RdKafka.Internal.LibRdKafka..cctor()
       InnerException:
```

the stacktrace looks like

```
in RdKafka.Internal.LibRdKafka.NativeMethods.rd_kafka_version()
in RdKafka.Internal.LibRdKafka.version()
in RdKafka.Internal.LibRdKafka..cctor()
```

i integrated the library via Nuget from https://www.nuget.org/packages/RdKafka/0.9.1-ci-131

can anyone tell me which assemblie i'm missing ?

Comment: It is a simple file-not-found error.  You surely forgot to copy the native DLLs that Kafka needs to your build directory, the Nuget package installer doesn't take care of it..  Use xcopy.exe in a postbuild event to copy the appropriate version of librdkafka.dll and zlib.dll  There are five flavors to choose from depending on OS and bitness, look in the packages/RdKafka.Internal.librdkafka.0.9.1-ci-16/runtimes directory

Comment: perfect, thats it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need install Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013

https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784